# Products sorting on indexByTaxon page

Tags: symfony, e-commerce, sylius

I'm trying to add ability to sort products by price and date. Are there any predefined methods to do that, or the only way is to implement them by hand? From `sylius.yml` we're getting such strange route:

```
%sylius.model.taxon.class%:
        field: permalink
        prefix: /t
        defaults:
            controller: sylius.controller.product:indexByTaxonAction
            sylius:
                template: SyliusWebBundle:Frontend/Product:indexByTaxon.html.twig
```

Which can be used like `{{ path(taxon) }}`. But just adding `sorting` parameter doesn't work for me. Any ideas?

Comment: Where did you add the sorting parameter? Under the sylius key? Which version do you use? Latest master?

Comment: @Paziツ, I use Sylius 0.11. It's already done with my own implementation, but if there is such functionality out of the box it will be great to write it here. I was trying `path(taxon, {'sylius': {'sorting': 'price', 'order':'desc'}})` or something like that. It was just a guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a version, which incorporates the [Pull Request #2122](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/pull/2122). Either the latest master, or you fork the 0.11 branch and cherry pick this fix.

Then you can simply define in your `config.yml` to only override the required defaults:

```
sylius_core:
    routing:
        %sylius.model.taxon.class%:
            defaults:
                sylius:
                    sorting:
                        order: desc
```

Comment: I've just tried to make fork of 0.11 and cherry pick another commit (unrelated issue) and stuck because there is no branch 0.11 - only tag. So is there any way to use version 0.11 + some cherry-picked commit.

Comment: `git checkout -b 0.11 v0.11.0` creates a new 0.11 branch with the v0.11.0 tag as starting point.